# (Introductory) Book suggestion about Groups, Rings and Fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, book-recommendation

I am looking to buy an introductory book about 'Groups, Rings and Fields'. I see that the SUMS series (Springer Undergrqduate Mathematics Series) offers the book of [D.A.R. Wallace](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4471-0425-4). In the past I have worked with other books of this series (Basic and Further Linear Algebra of Blyth and Robertson, Introductory Mathematics of Smith, Calculus of One Variable of Hirst, Introductory Mathematics of Marshall, Real Analysis of Howie). I greatly enjoyed these books; their style facilitates independent studying.

I have seen some reviews of the book of Wallace mentioning that there are several typos.

1. Despite the typos, does the book worth its value? Feel free to share your feedback (if any).
2. Is there a list of errata of the book?
3. Based on your experience, what other (of introductory nature, affordable and less than 300 pages) options should I consider?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I have found Aluffi's [Algebra: Chapter 0](https://bookstore.ams.org/view?ProductCode=GSM/104) to be a great book that starts from the very basics and builds up to more advanced topics. It is not less than 300 pages (though it contains a lot more than what you want) but I personally consider it great for self-study.

Comment: In spite of its name, the book doesn't cover Field theory at all, according to its contents, so if you're interested in some Galois Theory this book doesn't tell this story. The material is pretty basic and general, so if this is what you want try to page through it, and if you find its exposition nice, easy to read and friendly then get it.